# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#75) at 0x00AC7C10

Tags: c, visual-studio

Working on a program that handles linked list, at the delete portion of the list, I am supposed to free up the memory allocated, I keep getting this error when debugging: `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#75) at 0x00AC7C10`, but I am unsure where to look, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
void deleteFrames(struct Animation* pA)
{
    //using temp struct to cycle through and free each node that is not NULL
    struct Frame *tempDel;
    while (pA->frames!=NULL) {
        tempDel = pA->frames;
        pA->frames = pA->frames->pNext;
        free(tempDel->fileName);
        free(tempDel);
        tempDel = pA->frames;
    }
}
```

The breakpoint gets triggered on free(tempDel->fileName); I spoke to a friend and he told me it might be how I am memory allocating the string that I use to set the name of the frameName 
temp->fileName = malloc(sizeof(strlen(frameName))+ 1);

Comment: How many successful iterations are they? 
On which line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: `tempDel = pA->frames;` at the end of the loop is superfluous, beyond that there's nothing overly suspect about the code so we cannot help. I suggest taking a look at Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and if you're still stuck, then please post a [mcve]. :)

Comment: #75 is nice and early.  [To set a memory-allocation breakpoint in your program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2fhc9a3(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for points and tips, turns out how I was memory allocating for the frameName, I dropped sizeof out of: 
temp->fileName=malloc(strlen(frameName)+1);
and it worked just fine